# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot install Steam because of broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 20.04, steam

So, when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS onto my PC firstly I removed Nautilus (Because I prefer to use Nemo) and after this action my system has a lot of broken files that can't be removed (I tried and it's said that I have more and more broken files) and the command `sudo apt install -f` doesn't work at all. How can I fix it? I cannot install even Steam now also my system is up to date!

PS. aptitude doesn't work as well as apt.

```
sudo apt install steam
sudo password for lambleeg:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libudev1:i386 but  but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: If removing Nautilus caused all your problems you could try reinstalling it and just not use it.